# Does lambda capture support variadic template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

It would be nice if I could do the following:

```
template <class RT, class... PT>
class Event 
{
    ...
    void operator()(PT... args)
    {
        std::for_each(
            l.begin(), l.end(), [args...](Handler *p) { (*p)(args...); }
        );
    }
    ...
};
```

Unfortunately I couldn't make it compile with g++ 4.7.2 (-std=c++0x):

> evtempl.hh: In member function 'void elt::Event::operator()(PT ...)':
>   evtempl.hh:75:54: error: expected ',' before '...' token
>   evtempl.hh:75:54: error: expected identifier before '...' token
>   evtempl.hh:75:57: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
>   evtempl.hh:75:57: note:         'args'
>   evtempl.hh: In lambda function:
>   evtempl.hh:76:26: error: expansion pattern 'args' contains no argument packs
>   evtempl.hh: In instantiation of 'void elt::Event::operator()(PT ...) [with RT = void; PT = {int}]':
>   testevtempl.cc:28:9:   required from here
>   evtempl.hh:74:9: error: using invalid field 'elt::Event::operator()(PT ...)::::Handler*)>::__args'
>   evtempl.hh: In instantiation of 'void elt::Event::operator()(PT ...) [with RT = void; PT = {int, const char*}]':
>   testevtempl.cc:29:20:   required from here
>   evtempl.hh:74:9: error: using invalid field 'elt::Event::operator()(PT ...)::::Handler*)>::__args'

instead, I have to change that lambda to the old, mundane syntax:

```
for (itr = l.begin(); itr != l.end(); ++itr)
     (*(*itr))(args...);
```

This one compiles and works fine.

I wonder why the lambda syntax doesn't work.

1. Did I do something wrong or miss something?
2. Is such thing outlawed in the c++11 standard?
3. or, this is allowed by the standard, but it's
   a problem of the current compiler?

I tried

```
[=](Handler *p) { (*p)(args...); }
```

it gives the same error as if you did:

```
[args](Handler *p) { (*p)(args...); }
```

complaining parameter packs not expanded

Comment: Have you tried `[=]` instead?

Comment: @Kerrek SB good suggestion, but it doesn't work either

Comment: If you isolate the lambda `auto foo = [=](Handler *p) { (*p)(args...); };`, you get two errors "1) Parameter pack not expanded and 2) expansion pattern 'args' contains no parameter packs".  I suspect that it's a GCC bug, as it's complaing that args is both not a pack and must be one.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270941/can-a-parameter-pack-be-captured-implicitly-within-c11-lambdas

Comment: @lethal-guitar: That question is similar. However, this question uses explicit capture, while the linked question is talking about implicit capture.

Comment: @JesseGood ah yes, you're right.

Comment: It works on clang, http://liveworkspace.org/code/pstVG$3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in gcc. See [[c++0x]lambdas and variadic templates don't work together](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41933) or perhaps  [[C++11] Pack expansion fails in lambda expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55914).

Comment: Indeed, it's been a bug for a very long time already and as far as I know it is still a bug in gcc 4.8 and clang.

Comment: @gnzlbg, it's not a bug in clang.

Comment: @chico Cool! Thanks! I didn't knew it worked in clang already! If only expanding `f(args)...;` to `f(arg1), f(arg2), ...;` would work...

Comment: @gnzlbg there's this hack to expand a pack pattern merely for its side-effects: `std::initializer_list<int>{ (void(f(args)), 0)... };`. You can put it in a macro or something. And note that `{}`-initialization guarantees order of evaluation.

Comment: `f(args), 0` executes f(args), and evaluates to zero (look up comma operator if you are not familiar). I added `void` around f as a precaution against potential overloaded comma operators, which we don't want to kick in here (because you cannot overload it with a void argument). So I just build an initializer list full of zeros, that happens to execute all those side-effects. The initializer list is immediately discarded. Should have no overhead. Worst case scenario your compiler stores a readonly static array of zeros in your executable, but I would expect compilers to realize it isn't used.